# return multiple cell values based on string in Google sheets

Tags: arrays, filter, google-sheets, wildcard

I have a table with names and corresponding numbers. I want to return the numbers that correspond to ONE name. For this I need to search only in part of the name (string) given in row A (see image below) because some row entries only have 1 name and others have two names.

[Table with name and numbers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QJzuY.png)

So for example, I would like to return all the numbers that correspond to "William". I would expect to get the numbers 1 and 3.

In Google Sheets I have tried to use the following FILTER function:

```
=filter(B2:B7, A2:A7="*"&"William"&"*")
```

This did not work. It looks like it doesn't like I am using wildcards in my second parameter.

Does anybody have a solution to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a single function which will return a concatenated list of values from an array. But there is a long-winded workaround involving the `SEARCH()` and `CONCATENATE()` functions.

Please see [example Google sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Y2DPThKS65z0-MMiDfjDh_7NC84GezTDDotmxhFLh5w)

My answer to your specific question is in cell G9 which has the formula `=concatenate(G2:G7)` and

```
G2=if(iserr(search("william",A2)),"",B2 & " ")
G3=if(iserr(search("william",A3)),"",B3 & " ")
G4=if(iserr(search("william",A4)),"",B4 & " ")
G5=if(iserr(search("william",A5)),"",B5 & " ")
G6=if(iserr(search("william",A6)),"",B6 & " ")
G7=if(iserr(search("william",A7)),"",B7 & " ")
```

In the example worksheet I have made it a little more generic using `$` syntax so as to allow me to copy the formula in D2 across to fill the range D2:G7 without needing further alteration.

Incidentally, in these situations one often needs to sum up the values, and luckily there is the `SUMIF()` function for that. See cell G10 for an example `=sumif(A2:A7,"*William*",B2:B7)` of how to use it.